# Algorithm Visualization

Tags: algorithm

I wonder how it is possible to make a visual presentation of algorithm.

I found a very good visualization in Wikipedia like following:

[image]

If you know how to make a similar presentation, please let me know.

Comment: Make a visual representation of the state of your list (graph the elements), and in each step of your algorithm, indicate the change (e.g. swapping element 2 and element 6) and then update the graph.

Comment: what the easiest way to draw it, if there are any special tool to do so?

Comment: There are plenty of libraries, depending on the language.

Comment: It depends on what language you're working in. I don't know whether there are any automated tools specifically for this, that might be off-topic anyway, but I would just do it the same way I would do any graphics for the language in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of libraries in various languages that can be used to visualize whatever you want, but according to this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sorting_quicksort_anim.gif

The picture you're looking at was:

> Created with: Ruby 1.8.4, RMagick.

Just for reference.